# highcharts Xaxis timeflow

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Hello I would like to ask for an advice in setting X-axis in the chart. I am rendering 2500 samples like a 10 seconds of signal. How should I set X-axis to show continuous time. After new data rendered the time should continue. Something like I render first 2500 values and the last tick on X axis is 10 sec. Than another 2500 values come to be rendered and the time should continue from the beginning...11 and so on until 20 and so on. Can it be done with just simple add sth to xAxis ? Or I have to rework the rendering with data.push function.

```
                                    var options = {
                                        chart: { 
                                            renderTo: 'services',
                                            type: 'line', 
                                            animation: 'false'
                                        },

                                  xAxis: {
                                      labels: {
                                          formatter: function () {
                                              return (0 + (this.value / 250 )) + " sec";
                                          }
                                      }
                                  },

                                      plotOptions: {
                                            series: {
                                                animation: {
                                                    duration: 5000
                                                }
                                            }
                                        },

                                        series: [{marker: {
                                                    enabled: false
                                                }}]
                                      };
```

Comment: What data are you using? Are you defining x coordinate per data point is series data? or do you have ser pointStart and pointInterval set for series? How is you data.push function working? Could you post code for that?

Comment: Im not sure what exactly are you asking about.....But the data I´m rendering are just values taken from database. There are 2500 values in one plot and the tick in X axis is done after 250 values rendered.